# Is it possible to run Adobe Air application in the browser?

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, air, udp

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.rivellomultimediaconsulting.com/node-js-for-flash-and-flex-introduction/) that describes the way of connecting the node.js app with adobe action script 3.0. In that way I could present live video data (received by UDP from different application) to some other user. My question is - is it possible to make the video player with received data embedded on my html/php website? 
I checked the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) and there's a sentence:

`The DatagramSocket class can only be used in Adobe AIR applications and only in the application security sandbox.`

and on this [forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/414322?tstart=0) someone wrote:

> ```
> You can run an Adobe Air application FROM the browser.
> But you cannot run an Adobe Air applicatin WITHIN the browser.
>
> Indeed, Adobe Air wraps webkit (a very famous html rendering engine).
> Think of Adobe Air as a shell built around an browser.
>
> If you want to run something within the browser you can go with Flash/Flex.
> ```

But it's pretty old post, so maybe something has changed? Or maybe there's a way to convert the AIR app to Flash/Flex? 
Thanks!

Comment: No, nothing has changed. And you don't need to 'convert' anything, just don't use AIR-only capabilities in your Flash/Flex project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not exactly clear for me - so does that mean I can write the application using AIR and leave the compatibility mode with flash and flex - will I still be able to use all features of AIR (like receiving UDP packages, that apparently are being blocked in flash/flex)? And if so - will I be able to embed this 'app' in my webpage?

Comment: No, you cannot use AIR-stuff in webpages at all. AIR is for desktop and mobile devices only.

Comment: Hey @DodgerThud, thanks - so how does all the live video work then, since UDP is blocked in flash?

Comment: Flash uses the UDP-based protocol RTMFP. See http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-extended/rtmfp-faq.html

Comment: If you are looking for video streaming, check out [Red5](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server) server.

Comment: @randomuser1 the flash player 4.6 ꜱᴅᴋ contains a sample which demonstrate how to run the air runtime form the web browser. I mean,`http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf`?

Answer (score 1):

This can kind of be done. I'm not sure if you need it to run in the browser or not, but you could do an Install Badge. It allows the user to temporarily download the AIR file and run it on there computer from the browser through a seamless link without having to actually download and save the AIR files to there computer. You can read more here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e15.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

> What is ADOBE AIR?
> Adobe AIR is a cross-operating-system runtime that lets developers
> combine HTML, JavaScript, Adobe Flash® and Flex technologies, and
> ActionScript® to deploy rich Internet applications (RIAs) on a broad
> range of devices including desktop computers, netbooks, tablets,
> smartphones, and TVs. AIR allows developers to use familiar tools such
> as Adobe Dreamweaver®, Flash Builder®, Flash Catalyst®, Flash
> Professional, or any text editor to build their applications and
> easily deliver a single application installer that works across
> operating systems.

`Adobe AIR is used to run desktop applications` rather than content in the web browser, and just like a SWF file doesn't run in the browser without Flash Player installed, an AIR application won't work on your computer without Adobe AIR installed.

In short:
`Flash Player` is a `browser plugin` that takes adavantage over browsers incase `Adobe AIR` supporting users by providing RIAs in the `devices`.

And there is two kinds of AIR developemnt available for now.

1. `AIR with SWf:` AIR SDK with actionscript libraries.
2. `AIR with HTML:` HTMl and javascript within the AIR are handled by the open source Webkit/ javascript engine.

[Reference](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/air/faq.html)

Comment: **Wrong !** The Adobe 4.6 ꜱᴅᴋ come with a sample for running the air runtime form the web browser *(but the .air application will only call the air runtime)*. It requires at least Flash Player 9.

Comment: [Found the documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-1c6efe05128cca667e7-8000.html).